# __do_global_dtors_aux and __do_global_ctors_aux

Tags: c++, assembly, constructor, destructor, elf

I disassembled a simple program written in C++ and there are these two function names. I guess that ctor means constructor and dtor means destructor, and word global maybe means that they create and destroy global objects. I cannot guess the name aux. What do these two functions do?

Comment: aux = auxiliary http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/auxiliary

Comment: Also, you need to specify the processor and the compiler

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The addresses of *constructors* and *destructors* of static objects are each stored in a different section in *ELF executable*. for the constructors there is a section called **.CTORS** and for the destructors there is the **.DTORS** section.

the compiler creates two auxillary functions **__do_global_ctors_aux** and **__do_global_dtors_aux** for calling the constructors and destructors of these static objects, respectively.

**__do_global_ctors_aux** function simply performs a walk on the **.CTORS** section, while the **__do_global_dtors_aux** does the same job only for the **.DTORS** section which contains the program specified destructors functions.

Comment: "constructors and destructors of static objects" - to be precise, that's objects with _static storage duration_, such as globals. Not _static_ variables inside functions. The constructors for those variables are called from the containing function, not from `__do_global_ctors_aux`.

Comment: @MSalters is ctors and dtors only available in C++ binaries?

Comment: @warl0ck: They might be in D, I'm not familiar with the implementation details (They are in the D language, before compilation - but that's to be expected as D is designed as an alternative to C++ without C heritage)

Answer (score 12):

They are auxiliary functions added by the compiler to construct and destroy static objects.

e.g.

```
std::vector<int> some_global;

int main() { return 0; }
```

`some_global` needs to be actually constructed (and destructed) somewhere, and C++ guarantees that construction happens before `main`. One way to do this is to emit a function that happens before `main`, which constructs global objects, and another function that happens after `main` to destroy them.

If you stuck a breakpoint inside the `std::vector` constructor and ran this program, the stack trace would show you the function that it was being initialised from.