# Difference between call___do_global_ctors_aux and __do_global_ctors_aux

Tags: c++, c

I was reading this topic [__do_global_dtors_aux and __do_global_ctors_aux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477494/do-global-dtors-aux-and-do-global-ctors-aux) and I have a few questions, if possible.

1) How is call___do_global_ctors_aux different from __do_global_ctors_aux ?

2) Are string literals [string constants] the objects with static storage duration?

3) I use shared libs and see quite a few calls to call___do_global_ctors_aux during profiling(oprofile). Is there a way to reduce the number of calls to it? Is there any compiler flag to disable these or treat them differently.

Thanks

Comment: These functions should only run at program startup, so I find it odd that `oprofile` is finding them running often. Perhaps it's mistakenly identifying other unrelated code without symbols as being part of them.